# Replace string with array in preg_replace

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

I have a string which I want to filter. I want to find some words which I want to replace using `preg_replace`. My parameters are an array of words I want to take out from my string, and my replacements is just an empty space. Can someone please help me to solve this problem.

**My Code:**

```
$str = "Hello world. It's a beautiful day.";
$para = array("world","day");
$newstr = preg_replace('/\b($para)\b/','',$str);
echo $newstr;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
$str = "Hello world. It's a beautiful day.";
$para = array("/world/","/day/");
$newstr = preg_replace($para,'',$str);
echo $newstr;
```

Comment: Hi @sadlyblue. Thanks a lot for the answer. Its works just fine now.. Just another thing.. what if i want to replace "." (its a dot) also in string. actually i want to explode that string into array and finding space and than print the array but i dont want that dot to go into my array.

Comment: you want an array of all words with no dots and no spaces ?

Comment: Yes @sadlyblue. that's what i am planning. i wanted array of that string without any dots and empty spaces going in my array. My array will have one word at one location. example a string ="Good evening dear." and my array will be like array[0]=Good, array[1]=evening, array[2]=dear

Comment: use: $array = array_filter(preg_split( "/(\.| )/", $str ));

Answer (score 0):

Regex can't be an array but first parameter of `preg_replace` can be an array of regexes, you have to do:

```
$para = array("/\bworld\b/", "/\bday\b/");
$newstr = preg_replace($para, '', $str);
```

I've added word boundary arround the words, for not matching words like `daily`

Comment: Thanks @Toto. It was really helpful. Yes, i realized now.. if i had a word "band" in my string, final string would have been just "b" since i am replacing "and". Thanks again.